# UIPopoverController Memory Leak

Tags: ipad, ios4, nsarray, nsdictionary, uipopovercontroller

I have a universal app whose iPad portion uses a UIPopoverController which displays a UIViewController shared with the iPhone portion. When the iPhone version loads and releases the view controller, all is fine (no memory leak). When the iPad version loads it, two items, a NSDictionary and an NSArray leak.

In the view controller, the two objects are created and dealloc thus

```
- (void)setupModels {
    fonts = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
             @"Baskerville", @"Baskerville",
             @"Georgia", @"Georgia",
             @"HelveticaNeue", @"Helvetica Neue",
             @"Palatino-Roman", @"Palatino Roman",
             @"Verdana", @"Verdana", nil];

    fontNameKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"Baskerville",
                    @"Georgia",
                    @"Helvetica Neue",
                    @"Palatino Roman",
                    @"Verdana", nil];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [fonts release], fonts=nil;
    [fontNameKeys release], fontNameKeys=nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

The iPad version creates and dismisses the UIPopoverController thus

```
- (void)displaySettingsPopover:(id)sender {
    if([self.settingsPopover isPopoverVisible]) {
        //close the popover view if toolbar button was touched again and popover is already visible
        //Thanks to @chrisonhismac
        [self.settingsPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [self.settingsPopover.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:self.settingsPopover];
    } else {
        if (!self.settingsPopover) {
            //build our custom popover view
            PreferencesViewController_iPhone *pvc = [[PreferencesViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:nil
                                                                                                       bundle:nil
                                                                                               callbackObject:self
                                                                                                     selector:@selector(applySettingsFromPopover)];
            [pvc.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [pvc.navigationItem setTitle:@"Preferences"];
            [pvc setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320, 444)];

            //create a popover controller
            self.settingsPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pvc];
            [pvc release];
            self.settingsPopover.delegate = self;
        }

        //present the popover view non-modal with a
        //refrence to the toolbar button which was pressed
        [self.settingsPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                     animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    [self.settingsPopover setDelegate:nil];
    [settingsPopover release];
    settingsPopover=nil;
}
```

I'm not sure why the NSDictionary and the NSArray are leaking for the iPad but not the iPhone. The Profiler says their retain count initially sets to 1 but is never dealloc.

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, you might want to remove that manual call to the delegate. It shouldn't be done.

Comment: Without that line, popoverControllerDidDismissPopover: is not called when the user clicks the toolbar button to dismiss the popover. It is only called when the user clicks away from the popover. Perhaps there's a better way to manage this? I followed an example from another post.

Answer (score 4):

This line leaks:

```
self.settingsPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pvc];
```

if your `settingsPopover` is a `retain` or `copy` property, `retain` being very likely. Double check that, if that's indeed the case, autorelease it like so:

```
self.settingsPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pvc] autorelease];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the autorelease didn't help. When the popover is dismissed/released, the Dictionary and Array are not released. BTW, I added a NSLog() to the dealloc: to verify that it is being called when the popover is released, and it is. I suspect I could make those two objects mutable and remove their contents in the dealloc as well, but this doesn't seem like it _should_ be necessary.

Comment: Also, their @property definitions are (if helpful)

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *fonts;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *fontNameKeys;`

Comment: I've discovered a little bit more on this issue. It's not the closing of the popover that is creating the leak, it's the opening of it. That is, if I open the popover and leave it open long enough for the Profiler to create it's snapshot, I see the leaks for the Dictionary and the Array.

Comment: then it sounds like you're calling `setupModels` more than once.